# PredicateBuilder where clause issue

Tags: predicatebuilder

I am using PredicateBuilder to generate where clause

```
var locationFilter = PredicateBuilder.True<dbCompanyLocation>();
locationFilter = locationFilter.And(s => s.IsPrimary == true && s.State == practiceState);

var companyPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<dbCompany>();
companyPredicate = companyPredicate.And(c => c.dbCompanyLocations.Where(locationFilter));
```

I am getting following error, Any one can help for this or am i doing something wrong.

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem seems to be that `dbCompany.dbCompanyLocations` is an `EntitySet`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQueryable<T>`. This means its `Where` extension method expects a `Func<dbCompanyLocation, bool>`, however the `locationFilter` variable you are providing is an `Expression<Func<dbCompanyLocation, bool>>`.

You can create a `Func<dbCompanyLocation, bool>` from `locationFilter` by calling the `Compile` method.

Another problem however is that even if it did type check, `c => c.dbCompanyLocations.Where(locationFilter)` is not a predicate, since `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a bool. You probably meant to use `Any` instead of `Where` i.e.

```
companyPredicate = companyPredicate.And(c => c.dbCompanyLocations.Any(locationFilter.Compile()));
```